# Lazy loading hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

I use Spring 3 and hibernate 3.6.3.Final. I have to entities A and B. The hbm files are:

A.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.A" table="A" >
        <id name="A_Id" type="string">
            <column name="Id" length="100" />
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">B</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="B" class="B" constrained="true" fetch="select" ></one-to-one>
        <property>...</property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and B.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.B" table="B">
        <id name="B_Id" type="string">
            <column name="Id" length="32" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
...
        <one-to-one name="some_A" class="com.A" lazy="proxy"></one-to-one>       // FIRST
        <one-to-one name="other_A" class="com.A" lazy="proxy" cascade="all" >    // SECOND
            <formula>other_BSRC_REG_REP_MESSAGE_ID</formula>
        </one-to-one>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

From @Service I use the following code to get entity B by id:

```
getHibernateTemplate().get(getEntityClass(), id)
```

I enabled the show_sql mode in hibernate in order to check if my lazy loading works fine. Unfortunately I don't understand them

- When either FIRST or SECOND line is commented out hibernate shows exactly one query (where all of the one-to-one associations are present as join),
- When both FIRST and SECOND lines are uncommented hibernate shows two queries, one to get B and second to get an A entity.

Why this happens? Is it because all of the one-to-one association can't be lazy loaded so either they are eagerly loaded as a separate query or "joined" to the original query? If so, why hibernate didn't joined on the A table twice?